# Firefox extension: how to read a cookie name and value on the current page

Tags: javascript, firefox, cookies, xmlhttprequest, firefox-addon

My extension works on an application, which requires user login. Once the user has logged in, I need to read the cookies and use them in my [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest)s. 
So initially I need to check if the cookie is set, if not, I direct the user to the login page. Once logged in, I need to read the cookies and send it as part of my further requests.

How do I read cookies from a XMLHttpRequest or otherwise (if we don't even know the name of the cookie)

There is to function as getRequestHeader.. but what I need is something like that.

Answer (score 4):

The extension can access the Firefox cookies through the CookieManager XPCOM service. You can use it to read cookies, set cookies, etc. More information and code snippets here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Cookies

Comment: Could someone explain to me how this works. I am a bit confused about this code... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/zh-CN/firefox/addon/60/) toolbar in Firefox to read cookies. A cookie is a cookie no matter what sets it so it should show up the event it is set with an Ajax request.